# Make file to be owned by SYSTEM

Tags: windows

I have a file that needs to be owned by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for security reasons. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, in a batch file.

Comment: For future reference, describing what you have tried is considered good form when asking a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
icacls foo /setowner "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

Note that you'll need to be running in an elevated command window for this to work.

Comment: Note that you'll need to be running in an elevated command window for this to work.

Comment: Of course.  Seemed obvious to me but you're right and I'll add it to the answer.  Thanks!